# debugging or error log for UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication in a azure web site?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, owin, owin-middleware

I have an asp.net azure web api site, say myapi.azuresites.net, and my custom domain is myapi.mycompany.net.
In my web api, I use owin middleware to validate incoming token

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = Constants.AzureActiveDirectoryTenant,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        // These values will be checked against what is received in the access token.
                        ValidAudiences = Constants.AzureActiveDirectoryValidAudiences
                    },
                    Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProviderEx()
                });
```

I registered an app under azure AD and add some client secret in.

1. From postman, I can get an oauth2 token from Azure AD with the App id and the client secret.
2. I included this token in the header and sends to my azure web api.
3. My code uses owin middleware to validate the token
4. If I send the request to myapi.mycompany.net, the token validation works.
5. If I send the request to myapi.azuresites.net, the token validation fails.

I can't really figure out why the token validation fails when calling azure site directly. If I grab the azure site's web.config down to my local machine and it works there as well.
I suspected that my AD app didn't have the right redirect URLs, but verified that and can't see obvious issue.

So is there a way to log some information on why authentication fails? As it is a remote azure site, can I trap this failure as exception and throw some out?

Comment: so odd, I worked out a way to add some log, but then the authentication just worked

Comment: You can send your modified content as an answer, which can help more forum users who encounter similar problems.

Comment: ok, I posted what I found now

Answer (score 1):

Although not sure why my AD authentication works now, I did find [a way](https://dotnetdevlife.wordpress.com/2018/01/17/capture-owin-logs/) to log owin failures for azure site.
Basically this will log owin information

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources>
      <source name="Microsoft.Owin">
        <listeners>
          <add name="KatanaListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="KatanaListener" 
type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
 initializeData="d:\home\logfiles\Katana.trace.log"
traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime"/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
      <add name="Microsoft.Owin" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```